# Deploying ClickOnce Application With System.AddIn Support

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, add-in, maf

I have a ClickOnce app that I would like to have MAF (System.AddIn) support with.

I have learned about the System.AddIn Pipeline structure and such in a local context, but when it comes to ClickOnce, I can't find any information regarding such a feat.

Do I need to maintain the AddIn pipeline still in a ClicKOnce environment? 
As such, am I deploying the entire pipeline with the application? 
Are there any good links you guys have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everyone's benefit, this question was answered in the MSDN ClickOnce forum [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/ec8e8dc8-3253-4c97-bc3e-a3bc1f1bb97a).

Comment: or specifically [Deploying Add-ins by Using ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc176036(VS.90).aspx)